# Dual monitor set up

Tags: 18.04, multiple-monitors

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS. I'm trying to connect second monitor, but it's not getting recognized. How can I resolve this so my monitor works with Ubuntu?

The Monitor model is HCL - TFT17W80PS, product name is HCM7LWAT21.

In my laptop I have an HDMI port.

Photo of connector:

[image: Photo of connector]

Screenshot of Displays dialog:

[image: Screenshot of Displays dialog]

Comment: I can't say for sure... but I'd guess that giant chain of adapters is the issue. Generally, having chains of adapters will cause problems (like it not working, as you've observed). Please [edit] your question to include the model of monitor you are trying to connect to, as well as what port you are using on the laptop.

Comment: @cocomac I had mentioned model number and ports used.

Comment: Pls any one help here.

Comment: So it seems like you're trying to go from HDMI to VGA. I'm not sure exactly why you have that giant chain of adapters... but you could try an all-in-one HDMI to VGA adapter. There are [many on Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=hdmi+to+vga). Remember though: converting signals, especially from digital to analog or vice-versa, is not perfect, and sometimes simply won't work at all.

Comment: Okay, thanks @cocomac